# issue with sticky footer when keypad opens boostrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have created a web form with a header and footer in bootstrap 3.  on the pc it looks great on a tablet it looks good, on the phone it looks great until the keypad opens. Soon as that happens it seems as though the footer lands in the middle part of the form instead of the bottom. So when scroll to answer the input boxes on the form it looks awful and is in the way?  Would anyone know how to fix this? I am fairly new to bootstrap and I just cannot seem to see what it is I am missing.

You can see a working demo of this issue here
https://corker-chisel.codio.io/Form.html

Appreciate any help and guidance you can give :)

Gina

Comment: Footer remains at the bottom when keypad is opened. Keypad uplift your whole page. To overcome this problem, you need to keep the footer static instead of fixed positioned on mobile view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the footer scrollable on mobile views

```
@media (max-width: 767px)
    footer.navbar-fixed-bottom {
       position: static;
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thank you that worked like a charm :D and thank you so much for explaining why.... It now makes sense to me :)

Comment: I just discovered that by adding this fixed to my form I now have a new issue, it broke the footer on pages that do not have a lot of content. The footer now does not stick to the bottom :( I have tried playing with the media queries but have had no luck would you be able to suggest something for that ? corker-chisel.codio.io/Page2.html both pages are linked to one another so you can view the issue